# vswhere unable to find MSBuild after update to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.1

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, msbuild

I am using vswhere to find the installation path of MSBuild for some .bat-scripts. This was working fine until I upgraded to version 15.8.1 of Visual Studio 2017.

Now it comes up empty. This is my .bat-script:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%i in (`..\Tools\vswhere.exe -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild`) do (
     if /i "%%i"=="installationPath" set InstallDir=%%j)

echo %InstallDir%\Common7
```

Which has the following output:

```
\Common7
```

Has anyone else seen this issue? I've tried to update the vswhere.exe file to the one installed alongside the newest version of Visual Studio, but still no success. I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: I have test your bat file, it works fine on my side with Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1. What is the result if you execute this command line:`<VSWherePath>\vswhere.exe -latest -version "[15.0,16.0)" -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath`? Could you get the path? Check the document: https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It does not work either, unfortunately. The output when running this from the command line is only an empty text...

Comment: Running "vswhere.exe -all -property installationPath" returns the following path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional", but if I use "-latest" instead of "-all", it returns empty.

Comment: This is the vswhere version information: "Visual Studio Locator version 2.5.2+gebb9f26a3d [query version 1.17.1176.60362]"

Comment: That is strange. I test it on the other PC, it also works fine. Have you tried the command with the `vswhere.exe` directly from the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`? And have to tried it on the other machine?

Comment: I tried running vswhere.exe directly from the installation path now, still same result. I will try on another machine later. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I updated another computer (running Windows 7) to VS 15.8.1 and the command works there. I have run the command "vswhere -all" on both machines to compare the output. The W7 machine  (where it is working) has some additional properties that are not on my W10 machine:

"channelPath:", "properties_defaultProgram", "catalog_localBuild:".

Comment: Aslo, W10 has a value set for "properties_campaignId". W7 machine has that property, but no value set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to V 15.8.2 fixed my issue. Possibly something went wrong when installing version 15.8.1.